# New tab created on clicking the back button

Tags: bug, new-nav

I have a tab composed of any questions tagged [yii](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yii) or [yii2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yii2). The url for the tab is

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yii%20yii2
```

If I load any question and then use the back button, a new tab is created on the homepage with the url

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yii%20yii2?mode=all
```

as below:
[image]

Comment: Weird... I don´t see the any/all buttons. Through, I recommend using `[yii2] or [yii]`

Comment: @Braiam I've changed the tab definition as recommended. On clicking the back button, the url is correct but a new tab is still created.

Comment: @Braiam the any all buttons only appear if you do not type in `or` / `and`. They however do not reappear if you delete the `or` / `and`.

Comment: I just casually followed your link but without the dot at the end, now I did and saw the switch, but I can´t still reproduce the tab duplication behavior. What browser is this? Mine is Firefox 43.0.1

Comment: @Braiam on Firefox 45.0a2 and Chromium 47.0.2526.73

Comment: Bump. Happens for me on Chrome 53.0.2785.103 on ChromeOS.