# The new nav is out of date when using the “Back” button

Tags: bug, new-nav

Currently, [clicking the back button to return to the homepage makes a new tab](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/314028/5244995). Also, the tab’s contents are out of date.

After visiting a question from my React tab and clicking the back button:
[image: Outdated questions]

...but when I click one of the questions (“asked 4 mins ago”), I find:
[image: asked 2 DAYS ago]

Now that I’ve returned to the homepage, I again see the first screenshot. This time, I click on the “React” tab:
[image: And now for something completely different.]

I see the actual new questions.

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com